# Looping construct in a C99 macro

Tags: c, macros, c99

I want to generate an array initializer with arbitrary logic that unfortunately requires some looping.

```
#define RANDOM_ARRAY(n) \
    ...

double array[] = RANDOM_ARRAY(10);
```

Suppose the code above generates an initializer for a 10-element array. Is it possible to define such a macro (with a loop) in C99 ?

<sub>NB: it doesn't have to be a macro if a function call could suffice (but it has to be possible to call it among global initializers, not in a second function);</sub>

Comment: nah, suppose I dont want to type `array[] = { sin(1), sin(2), sin(3) ..., sin(10) };`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Fair point!

Comment: When you declare a global or static variable in C, it is initialized to all zeros.

Comment: @Yanko `sin(1)` etc involves a function call in C so it can't be used as an initializer the way the language is designed. You would have to invent your own look-up table behind macros... an entirely different question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C preprocessor doesn't support loops, so what you want is not (easily) possible.

I added the '(easily)' because there are ways to get loop-like behavior using something like [boost's ITERATE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/iterate.html). This uses recursive file inclusion to emulate a loop. But I'm not sure if you want to go that far.

Comment: @Yanko : the [boost preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/) library is

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create a recursive (or loop) macrofunction in C. Nevertheless, if you have a reasonable maximum length for your initializer, you can use this type of construct :

```
#define INITIALIZER(N)  { INITIALIZER_ ## N }
#define INITIALIZER_1   1
#define INITIALIZER_2   INITIALIZER_1, 2
#define INITIALIZER_3   INITIALIZER_2, 3


int
main(void)
{
    int tab[3] = INITIALIZER(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: won't this result int `int tab[3] = { INITIALIZER_3 }` ?

Comment: It should give `int tab[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in C99, you can of course create a macro that does the initialization, but you won't be able to make it look like an initializer:

```
#define INCREMENTING_ARRAY(t,a,n)    t a[n]; do {\
                                     for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)\
                                       a[i] = i;\
                                     } while(0);
```

This creates an array whose elements are initialized to be incrementing, as an example.

Usage:

```
int main(void)
{
  INCREMENTING_ARRAY(int, dozen, 12);
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof dozen / sizeof *dozen; ++i)
    printf("array at %d = %d\n", i, dozen[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

This works since in C99 you can freely mix declarations and code, so the `int i;`  after the macro usage is fine. In C89, it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: you need both the `do` and `for`?

Comment: This isn't initialization but run-time assignment.