# Can macro in c generate serialized statement?

Tags: c, macros, metaprogramming, code-generation

The code

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    SOME_MACRO(i);
```

does not work as expected because the macro isn't expanded with number but just the identifier `i`.

I want to find a macro can generate serialized statement like above. For example

```
GENERATE(0,3);
```

expand as

```
SOME_MACRO(0);
SOME_MACRO(1);
SOME_MACRO(2);
```

I tried recursion but don't know how to stop. Is there such macro?

Comment: Manu duplicate Qs e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543292/looping-construct-in-a-c99-macro

Comment: oh, I didn't found it before. This question will close.